# How to translate a day/time format that excel will understand

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I am working with an application that outputs this as its date and time:

2019-05-03T15:44:04+00:00

I am using Excel VBA, how do I edit this so that the time and date are separated by a space so I can format it so it shows proper output?

I haven't picked up this stuff in almost a decade, so I am a bit rusty, I am sorry if this is a "simple answer".

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
 Dim Dt as Date
 Dt = CDate(Replace(Left("2019-05-03T15:44:04+00:00",19),"T"," "))
```

Comment: This is going to be a list of dates... I used the date as an example so it's going to be a list between D2 and Dxxx because it's an unknown variable of how many entries on a daily basis.

Comment: @MattRidge then you will need to Loop through the cells and use the code above on each cell.

Comment: My brain isn't working right now, the ,19 isn't making sense to me... I thought that pointed to the 19th character...

Comment: It does, we need to get rid of everything after and including the `+`  the LEFT() does that.